# Hibernate unique in two columns

Tags: mysql, hibernate

Given a table of users with a username and email. Users can use username and email to log in. A user can choose an email as his username.

When a user changes his username or email, the new value must be **unique in the set of all usernames and emails combined**.

Is it possible to model this with hibernate notations, or would you need to do this at a higher level, like Java validation routines?

Small example:

```
| username | email      |
|----------+------------|
| user1    | a@smth.com |
| user2    | b@smth.com |
```

user2 changing his username to a@smth.com should be an illegal action, since user1 already has this value as his email.

Comment: sure.. @Column(unique = true)

Comment: I mean the username should be unique in all usernames AND all emails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @coladict said:

> then what you want is not supported by JPA or Hibernate. You can add a check constraint if your database version is 8.0.16 or above, but otherwise you'll have to do it manually before calling persist(user)

This is not in the realm of possibilities for hibernate. Our sollution is to do the check when validating the object. Of course this comes at the cost of computation and we have to make sure we have corresponding indices in the DB, to reduce the query time as best as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the sample code for your reference.

```
@Entity()
@Table(name = "users",uniqueConstraints= @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"email", "username"}) )
public class Employee {

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    //All other user entity fields and getters/setters etc......
}
```

Here is the [link](http://tech-fakhrul.blogspot.com/2015/03/hibernate-unique-constraint-on-multiple.html) for your reference.

Comment: I am not looking for a composite key, I want a new username or email to be unique in the set of all usernames and emails combined.

A new username should not be an existing email address.

Comment: @Le'nton then what you want is not supported by JPA or Hibernate. You can add a [check constraint](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html) if your database version is 8.0.16 or above, but otherwise you'll have to do it manually before calling `persist(user)`

Comment: @coladict Okay thanks. If you could add this as an answer I can accept it as well.